# AWS A record static ip or balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, server, hosting, amazon-lightsail

With [AWS](http://aws.amazon.com) I set up a static IP address and load Balancer, which of the two do we set with A record on the dns panel?

At the moment I have set it with the balancer, but I'm confused on the use of static IP and balancer. Is balancer balancing the static IP? And should we then use balancing as I'm doing or should I set the A record with the Static IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using load balancer for your route 53 record which will be configured as aliased A record. 
Any instance behind load balancer shouldn’t need public or elastic ip anyway. The reason for it is that all instances should be places inside private subnets which are routing out through NAT gateway.

Also, just to answer your question I may have misread.

A record is for Elastic Ip.
Aliased A record is used for load balancers.

Comment: ok so basically I have installed wordpress using lightsail, by following the tutorial on aws, they say there is the need of a static IP, so I created it. But then, I thought of installing load balancer, but you're saying there is not need. So I wonder, would you please specify in simple words what "load balancer is"? Thanks a lot

Comment: I don't think I'm using Elastic Ip, I didn't read it anywhere when setting up

Comment: So if we are talking about application Load balancer, it is an ALB which points at target group which is directing traffic to multiple ec2 instances. In general it is better to have multiple ec2 instances across multiple AZ to serve your traffic. If you have a single ec2 instance with public IP, you are relaying on the fact that this instance will always be there. In general it is a bad design. Single instance, single point of failure. Load balancer distributes the traffic across multiple target groups and effectively across multiple ec2 instances.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I'm not a sys admin. I could create a second instance, but that would install a second wordpress, what are you suggesting?

Comment: Hmmm, even with a single instance you should put it behind an ALB. ALB can be integrated with WAF which will protect your wordpress application by common threats. So, your best approach would be to configure ALB pointing at target group with your wordpress app. And then you will have route53 record which will be an aliased A record pointed at your load balancer. Ensure that your instance is in private subnet and doesn’t have a public IP as it is not required.

Comment: would you mind helping me out in setting this up via chat?

Comment: Absolutely, if you could reach out to me on https://uk.linkedin.com/in/marcincuber I would be happy to discuss tomorrow or Tuesday.